# AppiumDriver null pointer exception in determining the platform through environment variables

Tags: java, appium

`Appium` driver is thrown null pointer exception  while determining the platform through environment variables.

***Here is my code ***

public class AppiumBaseClass {
    public AppiumDriver driver;

```
@BeforeClass
public void setup() throws Exception {

    Properties prop = new Properties();
    InputStream input = null;
    String platform = System.getenv("PLATFORM");

    try {
        input = 
        new FileInputStream("/Users/piyushkumar/Desktop/Automation_Framework/HP_Signup/src/main/java/Utility/appiumSession.properties");
        prop.load(input);

        DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
        capabilities.setCapability("automation name", prop.getProperty("automation name"));
        capabilities.setCapability("platform",prop.getProperty("platform"));
        capabilities.setCapability("platformName", prop.getProperty("platformName"));
        capabilities.setCapability("platformversion", prop.getProperty("platformversion"));
        capabilities.setCapability("deviceName", prop.getProperty("deviceName"));
        capabilities.setCapability("app", prop.getProperty("app"));
        capabilities.setCapability("newCommandTimeout", "60");


        //Checking the platform
        if (platform.equals("Android")) {
            driver = new AndroidDriver(
                new URL("http://localhost:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities);
        } else if (platform.equals("ios")) {
            driver = new IOSDriver(new URL("http://localhost:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities);

        } else {
            throw new Exception("Unable to read platform");
        }

    } catch (IOException io) {
        io.printStackTrace();
        Reporter.log("platform selected is "+driver);
    }
}
```

}

**appiumSession.properties**

This is contents of the property file.

```
automation name = Appium
platformName= Android
platformversion=5.1
deviceName=Nexus_S_API_22
app= /Users/piyushkumar/Desktop/SignUpApp-qa-release-2.6-unaligned.apk
platform =Android
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: The stacktrace java.lang.NullPointerException
 at Utility.AppiumBaseClass.setup(AppiumBaseClass.java:45)

Comment: Which line is the 45? I think there is no capability like 'platform', only 'platformName' thus you get null pointer.

Comment: capabilities.setCapability("platform",prop.getProperty("platform"));                    This capability is for platform

Comment: the 'platform' capability does not exist, you have to remove it